# php:7.0.13-fpm failed to install gd

Tags: php, gd

I am trying to install gd on my php:7.0.13-fpm image

```
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-gd --with-webp-dir --with-jpeg-dir \
    --with-png-dir --with-zlib-dir --with-xpm-dir --with-freetype-dir \
    --enable-gd-native-ttf

RUN docker-php-ext-install gd
```

and it fails on:

```
#17 11.10 Installing header files:           /usr/local/include/php/
#17 11.40 php: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
#17 11.40 error: /usr/src/php/ext/gd/gd.so does not exist
#17 11.40
#17 11.40 usage: /usr/local/bin/docker-php-ext-enable [options] module-name [module-name ...]
#17 11.40    ie: /usr/local/bin/docker-php-ext-enable gd mysqli
#17 11.40        /usr/local/bin/docker-php-ext-enable pdo pdo_mysql
#17 11.40        /usr/local/bin/docker-php-ext-enable --ini-name 0-apc.ini apcu apc
```

Any ideas on how it should be configured?

Comment: Is the trace for the first RUN command or the second one?

Comment: @soulseekah second